# Web audio API - get current time of a source inside an AudioContext

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I would like to reproduce a simple sampler on my browser.

I've 4 different sources inside my same `AudioContext()`.
I managed to play/pause each source independently.

I'd like to get the current time of a source when I play it.
Unfortunately from what I read, I can only get the `currentTime` value of my context.

Is there a way to get the current time of a buffer source ?
Should I create 4 contexts with one source inside instead ?

Thank you very much

EDIT :
here's a preview, the sounds doesn't seems to play since it is on an https host. I'd like to get the current time of my source each time I click on play.

https://codepen.io/michaelgrc/pen/YzpMRZw

Comment: Can you show some minimal code that unambiguously shows what you're working with?

Comment: I just did, thank you very much

Comment: Please only add links [in addition to showing the minimal relevant code](/help/how-to-ask) in your post. If folks need to leave Stackoverflow to answer your question, it's not a good question =)

Answer (score 2):

If by "current time" of a source when it's playing, you mean to figure out where in the buffer source the output is currently playing, then the answer is that there's no way to do that.

However, see the [WebAudio V2 issue #26](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api-v2/issues/26) that might help with what you want.

Comment: but how can one **set** the currenttime?

Comment: You can't.  It's managed automatically by browser.

Comment: i meant of the audio source playing

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Can you provide more info or example of what you want to do?  (Probably another SO question instead of here.)